# jquery-confirm - How to send href link to browser

Tags: jquery, href, alert, confirm

I'm using this nice plugin jquery-confirm v3.0.3 (http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) to confirm actions

But when using the code below, **the href action from my link** is not executed when i press the OK button ?

What i'm doing wrong ? Thanks for your help...

```
<a class="delItem" href="?del=true&id=1">Supprimer</a>

$('a.delItem').confirm({
            title: 'Confirmer cette action',
            content: '',
            animation: 'left',
            theme: 'light',
            type: 'red',
            autoClose: 'cancel|10000',
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    text: 'OK'
                },
                cancel: {
                    text: 'Annuler',
                    action: function () {
                    //$.alert('action is canceled');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Should your confirm button have an action set to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add action function inside confirm block (like on cancel) and inside that:

```
window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add

```
location.href = this.$target.attr('href');
```

in your OK button like

```
$('a.delItem').confirm({
  title: 'Confirmer cette action',
  content: '',
  animation: 'left',
  theme: 'light',
  type: 'red',
  autoClose: 'cancel|10000',
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      text: 'OK',
      location.href = this.$target.attr('href')
    },
    cancel: {
      text: 'Annuler',
      action: function () {
        //$.alert('action is canceled');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works with location.href = this.$target.attr('href');
But if i want to pass POST request ?
In the last version of jquery-confirm it was possible without the needs of location.href = this.$target.attr('href');

Comment: @Chris I've never used `jquery-confirm`, but seems like you can use "normal" `ajax` request https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#content-loaded so just set method and data like explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: Thank you. It's just that the version 2 of this plugin took care, before, of the POST request. I'm going to use the $.ajax method now ;))